# grep with $ in string

Tags: r, regex

In R How do I grep something which has a $ in string. In This below example I need to grep  string "NB6106$MU-MU.rma"

```
x<-c("NB6106$MU-MU.rma", "NB610634$MU-MU.rma")

x[grep(pattern="*6106$*.rma", x = x)] #does not work
```

Comment: Use :\\$ to prevent the interpretation.

Answer (score 6):

You may use

```
x<-c("NB6106$MU-MU.rma", "NB610634$MU-MU.rma")
x[grep(pattern="6106\\$.*\\.rma", x = x)]
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/uAs5JG)

**Details**

- `6106\\$` - `6106$` substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `\\.rma` - a `.rma` substring

If you plan to make sure you do not grep `11116106$...rma`, you may use

```
"(^|\\D)6106\\$.*\\.rma$"
```

where `(^|\\D)` matches start of string (`^`) or (`|`) a non-digit char (`\D`), and `$` at the end ensure the end of string appears right after `.rma`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it. $ by itself in a regular expression indicates the end of the string, so you need to tell R that here you mean it literally as a $, which is done by escaping. The escape character is `\`. So, in theory, you'll type in `\$`. BUT, since you're writing the pattern as a literal string (within quotes), you ALSO need to escape the escape character, so that R knows to transfer it literally to the regex interpretor. Hence: `\\$`.

Other issues with your code: * doesn't mean "any characters". It means "repeat the previous character zero or more times". `.` means any character, and `.*` means any number of any character, which is what you're looking for. And of course, if you want a literal period, you need to escape that too: `\\.`